# Spring Security OAuth2 SSO with Custom provider + logout

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement sso with Spring Security Oauth2 using Spring-boot and Dave Syer samples

I want to use my [custom server](https://github.com/ikane/demo-sso-oauth2-server) provider and it's working fine.

For the client, I want user to be authenticate (so redirected to OAuth2 url) when they try to access client site (eg localhost:8080/) and redirect back to index.html file once authenticated. I also want to implement logout when user on a link in index.html file.

I've come up with this following client sso client:

```
package org.ikane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class DemoSsoOauth2ClientApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoSsoOauth2ClientApplication.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        try {
            Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
            logger.info(authentication.getDetails().toString());

            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoSsoOauth2ClientApplication.class, args);
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        logger.info("\n\thttp://localhost:{}{}\n\tProfiles:{}\n", 
                StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(env.getProperty("server.port"), "8080"), 
                StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(env.getProperty("server.contextPath"), "/"),
                Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * The Class OAuthConfiguration that sets up the OAuth2 single sign on
     * configuration and the web security associated with it.
     */
    @Component
    @Controller
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    protected static class OAuthClientConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN";
        private static final String CSRF_ANGULAR_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                    .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null
                                && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie(CSRF_COOKIE_NAME, token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
                            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        /**
         * Angular sends the CSRF token in a custom header named "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
         * rather than the default "X-CSRF-TOKEN" that Spring security expects.
         * Hence we are now telling Spring security to expect the token in the
         * "X-XSRF-TOKEN" header.


         * 
         * This customization is added to the csrf() filter.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName(CSRF_ANGULAR_HEADER_NAME);
            return repository;
        }
    }

}
```

You can find a [GitHub source](https://github.com/ikane/demo-sso-oauth2-client). Any hints on how to implement this use case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

- To make your client app redirect to the Authorization Server just add
  the annotation `@EnableOAuth2Sso` on your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and 
  place the proper OAuth2 configurations (client-id, secret, access token uri...) in your properties file.
  (I'm assuming that your client app is using Spring Boot as well)
- To end the user's session you have to redirect to an endpoint in the authorization server and logout programmatically as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071370/spring-boot-oauth2-single-sign-off).

I have created a [repository on github](https://github.com/juanzero000/spring-boot-oauth2-sso) with a sample app that has those features that you are looking for.

Please check it out and let me know if it helps you.