# Spring Boot OAuth2 Single Sign Off (Logout)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm considering to use OAuth2 for my application. The architecture I'm trying to implement is as follows:

- I will have my own (and only this) Authorization Server
- Some Resource Apps validating access to their resources using the Authorization Server
- Some client apps (web, mobile) which will redirect the user to the Authorization Server for authentication and on success will consume the api's on the Resource Apps.

So far I have managed to implement this interaction between 3 basic apps (1 auth server, 1 resource server and 1 client). The thing I don't get working is the logout functionality. I have read of the ["notoriously tricky problem"](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v#the-logout-experience) that Dave Syer describes in his tutorial, but in this case I really need the user to re-login after loging out. I have tried giving few seconds to the access token and the refresh token, but instead of being prompted to login again when the expiration arrives, I'm getting a NPE on the client app. I have also tried the solutions proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987589/spring-security-how-to-log-out-user-revoke-oauth2-token) to remove the token from the token store, but it doesn't work. The single sign off is for me the desirable behaviour for this implementation. How can I achieve this using Spring Boot Oauth2. If it is not possible for some reason, which alternatives I could use to implement a centralized security using Spring Boot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a lot of tests I have realized that this can be solved just with a redirect to the AuthServer and doing logout programmatically like this:

- In the client app (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter):

  ```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
              .logout()
              .logoutSuccessUrl("http://your-auth-server/exit");
  }
  ```
- In the authorization server:

  ```
  @Controller
  public class LogoutController {

      @RequestMapping("/exit")
      public void exit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
          // token can be revoked here if needed
          new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, null, null);
          try {
              //sending back to client app
              response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I have posted a [sample app on github](https://github.com/juanzero000/spring-boot-oauth2-sso) with a full example of this implementation.

Comment: This simple answer led me to a simple solution.

Comment: What is this code doing? Logging out from a client app (website) logs out the user from the one authorization server? Does it mean when user logged in to multiple clients app, logging out from one of them would lead to logging out from all of the clients app?

Comment: @eugene I have tested this solution using 2 client apps and when logging out from one doesn't affect the other. What this solution does is that when you click logout and then click login again you have to re-enter your credentials. Is an alternative to solve the ["notoriously tricky problem"](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v#the-logout-experience).

Comment: What if I don't want to  logoutn from resource server? I just want to logout my application from that resource

Comment: @Juan Carlos Mendoza which one should be done first? logging out from client or auth server? Isn't it more secure to log out from auth server first by client sending log out request to auth server with token, auth server verifies token and if valid logs out and then redirects to client log out endpoint?