# Security OAuth2 Single Sign Off

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, token, spring-security-oauth2

I have two clients (client1, client2) and an OAuth (authorization, resource).

I want to logout from one of clients and the other will be logout. I have tried this [spring-boot-oauth2-single-sign-off-logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071370/spring-boot-oauth2-single-sign-off-logout) but this only logout my client1 and client2 is still logged in!

Then I try to revoke my tokens while I use this code below:

```
String username = principal.getName();
Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> accessTokens = tokenStore.findTokensByClientIdAndUserName("client1", username);
accessTokens.forEach(a -> tokenServices.revokeToken(a.getValue()));
```

This code did not work, even the client1 is still logged in! While I see my redis is empty and there is no token already, but my client1 is still logged in! How that possible?

===========================================================================
Here is my configuration:

**Client - application.yml:**

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /clt1

spring:
  application:
    name: client1

  thymeleaf: 
    cache: false

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: client1 
      client-secret: secret1
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8000/oa/oauth/authorize
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:8000/oa/oauth/token
      scope: read, write
      #pre-established-redirect-uri: http://localhost:8081/clt1/callback 
      #registered-redirect-uri: http://localhost:8081/clt1/callback
      #use-current-uri: false 
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8000/oa/user 
      #jwt:
      #  key-uri: http://localhost:8000/oa/oauth/token_key 

logging:
  level:
    root: info
```

**Client - SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers().permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8000/oa/revokeClient").permitAll();
    }

}
```

**Oauth - application.yml:**

```
server:
  port: 8000
  servlet:
    context-path: /oa

spring:
  application:
    name: security

  redis:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 6379

  thymeleaf: 
    cache: false

logging:
  level:
    root: info
```

**Oauth - AuthorizationConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("client1")
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret1"))
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8081/clt1/login")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .and()
            .withClient("client2")
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret2"))
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8082/clt2/login")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

}
```

**Oauth - ResourceConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

**Oauth - SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)//SecurityConfig >> ResourceConfig
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/loginPage", "/login**", "/registerPage", "/register", "/oauth/authorize", "/revokeClient")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registerPage", "/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/docs/**", "/fonts/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/plugins/**");
    }

}
```

**Oauth - Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class SsoDemoOauthApplication {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new RedisTokenStore(connectionFactory);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoDemoOauthApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: what kind of token are you using ?

Comment: I'm using redis tokenstore. And I have tried jwt but it dose not work too.@JEY

Comment: Could you provide your spring configuration ?

Comment: Hi @JEY. I pasted all my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I admit not beeing too clever, but what about putting

```
.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8000/oa/logout").permitAll();
```

instead of

```
.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8000/oa/revokeClient").permitAll();
```

in SecurityConfig of client app? Any drawback?

Comment: I tried this. Actually it logout my client1, but client2 is still logged in. :(